# Using web service to populate treemap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using `d3.js` and populate a treemap. I'm retrieving the data in a `JSON` format from a `web service` which is written in C#. The data return is perfectly fine because if I copy the output and use it for `var treeData` the treemap displays as expected. However when I make the `ajax` call and use it to populate graph, I only get one circle on the screen. My Code is below

```
<script>
    var dataFromAjax;
    var treeData;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyService.asmx/JsonValue",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var a = JSON.parse(data.d);
                dataFromAjax = [JSON.stringify(a)];

                setTreeData();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    function setTreeData() {
        treeData = [dataFromAjax];

        root = treeData[0];
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;
      ...
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is it because the data is converted to a string perhaps?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've posted that would draw a circle (or anything else). You also don't need `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @StaceyBurns was because it was being converted to string I removed `JSON.stringify` and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I thought `JSON.parse()` should be used to get the data from a web service.. Sorry I'm pretty new to d3 so hence my knowledge is not probably the greatest

Comment: You don't need to parse the JSON if you retrieve it like this.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I did try it without parsing the JSON but it doesn't work.

Comment: How does it not work? What code did you run?